# Paging through search results with MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, pagination

Is there and easy way to do this ?  I have the search working ... I have paging working but not together

So the easiest way to me seems to just cache the search results and then refer to that collection in the controller as the collection to page through.. Does that make sense ?

Or how should I approach this from a high level   ?   (I come from 10 years of ASP.NET webforms)

Answer (score 1):

Caching search results improves performance of paging through the results data, but consumes memory. If searches are done by multiple users you need to cache search results for each user. Depending on the potential amount of data to be held in memory this may or may not be feasible. (Such caching should be done for a short time with sliding/absolute expiration.)

Doing search every time you need to provide data for the current result page creates higher CPU load, but does not consume memory between requests. Of course, request for page data must carry search parameters, so that the search can be redone.

This is the usual compromise between placing more stress on CPU or memory, and it is up to you to decide what to choose. I would cache the results with a short sliding expiration time (1 minute) and still make sure that the search can be performed again if the cached result is not present.